# Neo4J: query based on partial values of a node key

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a csv data set that contains a column of times and a column of days.

Sample data looks like this:

First row
`"9:00 - 15:00", "Monday, Tuesday"`

Second row
`"10:00 - 14:00", "Saturday"`

Third row
`"10:00 - 14:00", "Saturday"`

There is multiple repeating data, and because of this the day and the time together create a unique id so only these unique values will be in the node.

I create a constraint on this as follows:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (o:OpeningHours) ASSERT (o.openingTimes, o.openingDays) IS NODE KEY
```

I load the csv file and create the nodes as follows:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///OpeningHours.csv' AS row 
WITH row.times AS openingTimes, row.days AS openingDays 
MERGE (o:OpeningHours {openingTimes: openingTimes, openingDays: openingDays})
SET o.openingTimes = openingTimes, o.openingDays = openingDays
```

Now I want to return the nodes for all of the opening hours for Saturday, so I do this:

```
MATCH(o:OpeningHours)
WHERE o.openingDays CONTAINS 'Saturday'
RETURN o
```

However, this query doesn't return anything. Is there a way to to this query based on a partial node key or am I off the ball completely?

Thanks guys.

EDIT:

When I run the following query

```
MATCH (o:OpeningHours)
RETURN o.openingDays
LIMIT 3
```

I get the following result:

First row
`"Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday"`

Second row
`"Saturday"`

Third row
`"Sunday"`

EDIT 2:

I have solved the problem, it was a typo that I didn't pick up on!

Comment: Can you show some actual data? What do you get from this query: `MATCH (o:OpeningHours) RETURN o.openingDays LIMIT 3`.

Comment: I've edited my question to include the result of that query

Comment: If it was just a typo, then you should probably close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
MERGE (o:Opening {openingTimes: openingTimes, openingDays: openingDays})
```

you create nodes with label  `Opening` instead of `OpeningHours`

Comment: Apologies, this was a typo I made when writing out the question. The query still doesn't give any output.

Comment: Does your query return expected result when uou remove the WHERE clause?

Comment: When I remove the where clause and have the query as ```MATCH (o:OpeningHours) RETURN o``` I get all of the nodes displayed with their properties